# Having an issue loading resource from assetmanager

Tags: libgdx

I am using assetmanager to laod a .pack file

```
    //load assetmanager textures
    Manager.load("Pong.pack", TextureAtlas.class); << line 34

    Manager.finishLoading();

    TextureAtlas atlas = Manager.get("Pong.pack");
```

the line with this << is the culprit from the log

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.Shadow.Pong.Game.Assets.init(Assets.java:34)
```

I pointed the working directory to the resource folder for the desktop module. So i dont know why it keeps saying nullpointerexception.

thanks in advance

Comment: Either `Manager` is null (most likely) or `TextureAtlas` is null.  You'll have to provide more information to clarify the status of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Realized that i didint call a new assetmanager for the parameter for the asstmanager call so thats why it was giving the nullpointer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 TextureAtlas atlas = Manager.get("Pong.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
```

having a wild guess because many information are missing.

I mean what exactly in Asset.java line 34.
Manager instantiated or not and many other things.

But i guess one i suggested seems to be the problem